# API recovery how to display it in a <select>?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

currently internship I have to make a website with the establishment of an external API, I can display the data, parcontre I would like the displays in a `<select>`

However when I make my code nothing is displayed, however if I display it in a data p appears but in a table, how to display the data in a `<select>`

```
function dog_func ($atts) {
    $contents = file_get_contents('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all');
    $contents_arr = json_decode($contents);
    echo "<select>" . $contents ."</select>" ;
}
add_shortcode ('dog_api', 'dog_func');
```

OR

```
function dog_func ($atts) {
     $contents = file_get_contents('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all');
     $contents_arr = json_decode($contents);
     echo '<select multiple value="$contents"></select>';
}
add_shortcode ('dog_api', 'dog_func');
```

During these tests nothing is displayed

AND

```
function dog_func ($atts) {
    $contents = file_get_contents('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all');
    $contents_arr = json_decode($contents);
    echo "<p>" . $contents ."</p>" ;
}
add_shortcode ('dog_api', 'dog_func');
```

Walk but display in "gross"

Comment: Are the responses just json arrays with the values, or is it a json object containing other data as well?

Comment: just an array with JSON values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for `<select>` like this

```
$contents_arr = json_decode($contents);
echo '<select>';
foreach($contents_arr->message as $key=> $ca){
 echo "<option value='".$key."'>" . $key ."</option>" ;
}
echo '</select>';
```

And for `<p>`

```
$contents_arr = json_decode($contents);

foreach($contents_arr->message as $key=> $ca){
 echo "<p>" . $key ."</p>" ;
}
```

It's actually a json object which you can decode it into the array and then parse it through `foreach` loop

Comment: I try your example but it does not work, more simply I would like to clean my data displayed in a simple list, How to clean it                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                {"status":"success","message":{"affenpinscher":[],"african":[],"airedale":[],"akita":[],"appenzeller":[],"basenji":[],"beagle":[],"bluetick":[],"borzoi":[].....}

Comment: Clean meaning?.

Comment: Clean this  {"status":"success","message":{"affenpinscher":[],"african":[],"airedale":[],"akita":[],"appenzeller":[],"basenji":[],"beagle":[],"bluetick":[],"borzoi":[].....} and after affenpinscher                                                                                                        african .....

Comment: `$contents` is a normal PHP array. You can write `$content = $content['message'];` and `$content` should contain only the message array ("affenpinscher" and so on). Make sure that you call `json_decode` beforehand.

Comment: I had a look at the structure of the API content again and noticed that "messages" is an object and not an array. Therefore you need to write `$content = $content_arr->message;` You can check this by calling `print_r($content_arr);` and PHP will output something like "stdClass Object".

Comment: Is this the data which you want to show in `select` and `p`

Comment: Is it possible to just delete all the punctuation and success so that just the race appears in a list?

Comment: @ZainFarooq Yes I would like to appear in front of the board without displaying the table in front of the board

Comment: @JeanneThibert I have updated my answer. Now races are being displayed on the select and p tags

Comment: I am glad that I could help you. Cheers :)

Comment: @Johannes Thank you very much, it allowed me to understand the code